# Codeship skip ci for tagging

Tags: codeship

I've tried several ways to skip ci but it doesn't work.

```
git tag -a $NEXT_TAG -m "Bump version --skip-ci"
git tag -a $NEXT_TAG -m "Bump version [skip ci]"
```

Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: P.S.: you can submit feature requests on the Community Forum at https://community.codeship.com/c/feedback/feature-request. Please make sure to search for a similar request before opening a topic firs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipping builds triggered from tags is currently not supported by Codeship.

Comment: Is there any chance that this feature will be available in future? Is there any ETA for it?

Comment: We're looking into this right now, but I can't make any promises yet or share an ETA.